# Angularfire signInWithEmailLink invalid email link

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, angularfire

I'm using AngularFire's `signInWithEmailLink` wrapper for Firebase authentication.  I am passing a valid email address and the return url as arguments, but without even making any network request to Firebase, the method throws an error "Invalid email link!".  This, I'm assuming, is in reference to the second method argument which is supposed to be a string.  I cannot determine what I'm doing wrong in this case.

For example:

```
// signInWithEmailLink(emailAddress: string, emailLink: string)
this.auth.signInWithEmailLink('dave@example.com', 'https://my-app/email-link-return');
```

There is no AngularFire documentation about this particular method specifically.  One is encouraged to read the Firebase docs for each wrapped method, however on consulting the Firebase docs for the same method, the arguments are very different altogether.  Has anyone figured this out?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure whether you are actually checking if the link is a sign in URL but here's how you verify it.

```
if (this.auth.isSignInWithEmailLink(url)) {
  let email = window.localStorage.getItem('emailToSignIn');
  
  if (!email) {
    email = window.prompt('Please provide your email for confirmation');
  }

  const result = await this.auth.signInWithEmailLink(email, url);
  window.localStorage.removeItem('emailToSignIn');
}
```

If the doesn't help, please update your question with a detailed error. Most common errors include link expired, already used or something but there should be some additional info in the console to debug it.

Comment: OMG I was using the wrong method altogether <insert embarrassment>.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, after reading @Dharmaraj answer I realised I was using the wrong method.  I was trying to send the email link using `signInWithEmailLink` instead of `sendSignInLinkToEmail`.  Posting the answer here just in case anyone else is a dumb as I was.